# Formatting textbox input correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox

So I'm developing a user-user private messaging system and I'm getting a little confused on one thing.

Ideally users should be able to enter text as they want it to appear in the message and it should appear that way for the recipient.

This is not the case. Things like carriage return/line feed characters aren't being rendered. It all ends up in a giant mess of a paragraph on the page...

I know a rich text editor like tinymce will do what I want, but I kinda have it in my head that there's an easier way to achieve the desired result here.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The issue arises because textareas contain text, so new lines are text newlines (one of "\r", "\n", or "\r\n" depending on the OS). You will need to handle this and replace it with the equivalent html tag ("<br/>"). The simplest way would be to do the following:

```
string OutputString = InputString.Replace("\r\n", "<br/>").Replace("\n", "<br/>").Replace("\r", "<br/>");
```

Comment: and I could specify `[b]this is bold text[/b]` and replace in the same way? What about <p>...</p> tags? I'd have thought a \r\n would be one of those whereas as <br /> would be \n alone...

Comment: the difference between "\r\n" and "\n" is unfortunately not that simple. Different OS handle new lines in different ways, so the difference tells you which OS the client was on, and that's it.

To specify bbcode, you can deal with things like [b] in the same way, but if you start adding complex bbcode (like links that may require attributes) you would need to look into Regular Expressions.

Comment: I see... Thanks :) I'll try it out and see what I can make work. Will mark as answer when I see it works